# Limit CPU usage in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, cpu-usage

I would like to ask if it's possible to limit the CPU usage of Vscode? I saw some articles related to disabling extensions and typescripts and it works as it does not clog the CPU but on the system side or in the Vscode itself, would it be possible to force limit the resources that code can consume?

I am using vscode in remote (Windows using ssh) and in a shared virtual machine - Centos 7 which affects other users when my Vscode clogs the CPU.

Thank you in advance for the answers!

Comment: Kimmy. I think this question was already answered.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59075779/13459527)

Comment: Hi @Modev, Thank you for your reply but I think my question is different and hasn't been answered yet.. would it be possible to force limit the resources that code can consume? 

I think most of the answer to limit the CPU is related to disabling extensions and some settings but in running Vscode or in Linux System is it possible to force limit the maximum CPU percentage that code can consume?

Comment: can you change the priority of the VSC process to very low so all other stuff gets done first

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to limit the CPU usage of a process/application at the OS level.

You can read about how to do it in [Windows here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-limit-CPU-usage-for-a-particular-application-in-Windows-For-example-I-do-not-want-Chrome-to-use-more-than-50), and
[CentOS here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151883/limiting-processes-to-not-exceed-more-than-10-of-cpu-usage)

I do not entirely understand your setup (are you connecting to the vscode-server, or VSCode UI via something like RDP), but you would need to limit the resource usage on the machine running the server (aka. the remote machine).