# Why the 1.69.2 vscode server has so high CPU usage （>50%）?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use VS Code latest version 1.69.2 , and remote connect to my cloud VM.  After one or two days， I found the cpu usage is very high .The detail of the process is :
my-user  18954 17082  0 12:10 ?        00:00:04 /home/my-user/work/.vscode-server/bin/3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a/node /home/my-user/work/.vscode-server/bin/3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a/out/bootstrap-fork --type=extensionHost --transformURIs --useHostProxy=false

There are 8 node processes in total，every cpu usage is large than 50%

The question is:

1. What process is this?
2. Why the cpu usage is so high?
3. When I close all the connected windows and then reconnect to my remote VM, these processes are still here. Why are these processes not closing automatically?

Is this the bug of VSCode 1.69.2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code using large amounts of CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886037/visual-studio-code-using-large-amounts-of-cpu)

Answer (score 4):

VSCode uses Node, I suppose it's one of these process used for autocomplete that scans your files, but it's never ending. I have to kill them manually, 1 node process uses 100% of the CPU.

I solved the issue by removing the .vscode-server folder created in my home folder. You have to do this from a remote shell (not from vscode terminal).

Comment: Seems like it's working. Hoping that Microsoft will fix this soon.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by removing the Settings Sync plugin。

Comment: where did this extension come from. I don't remember installing it